# React - How to conditionally display fetched data

Tags: reactjs, graphql

If there are no docs in my docs folder, I want to display "There are no docs at the moment", but when I do it this way, I get a warning saying

```
warn The GraphQL query in the non-page component
"/Users/abe/Projects/abechoi/gatsby1.0/abechoi/src/templates/doc-template.js"
 will not be run.
```

Is there a better way to make this happen, or should I just ignore this warning?

```
export default function Docs({ data }) {
  const docs = data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.docsContainer}>
        <h2>Docs</h2>
        <h3>My Technical Documentations</h3>
        {docs.length === 0 ? (
          <p>There are no docs at the moment</p>
        ) : (
          <div className={styles.docs}>
            {docs.map(doc => (
              <Link to={"/docs/" + doc.frontmatter.slug} key={doc.id}>
                <div>
                  <h3>{doc.frontmatter.title}</h3>
                </div>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query DocsPage {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { type: { eq: "doc" } } }
    ) {
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          title
          slug
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GraphQL query complaints in non-page component for GatsbyJS website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912470/graphql-query-complaints-in-non-page-component-for-gatsbyjs-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a child component that's doing all the checks and then render the good component.

```js
  function CompletedButtons() {
    if (buttonStatus === "pause" || buttonStatus === "start") {
      return <StartButton />;
    } else if (buttonStatus === "inProgress") {
      return <Pause />;
    }
    return <ResetButton />;
  }
```

in the JSX it will look something like that.

```html
        <div className='buttonContainer'>
          <CompletedButtons />
        </div>
```